# find part of the webpage that is not visible only from above

Tags: jquery

How can I find the total height of the webpage which is not visible only from above the visible area on the browser. I've been combing everywhere and can't find an answer

edit.

when someone scrolls down a webpage, I'm trying to find in px how much height is not visible from what is above the current screen

Comment: Can you please reword your question - it's hard to understand what you're after. I'm having difficulty understanding "which is not visible only from above the visible area".

Comment: I'm sorry, I have having a tough time understand what you want to know.  Are you asking how to find the largest z-index? Or... something else?

Comment: Sounds like he may be talking about the entire web page, not just the viewport.

Comment: I need webpage height above viewpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, try:

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height();
```

`$(document).height()` gives you the height of the entire document.

`$(window).height()` gives you the height of the viewport.

The difference of the two should yield the non-visible portion part of the document.

`$(document).scrollTop()` should give you the non-visible portion from the top of the document to the current scroll position.

Comment: that only gets me the total height I need total_height - height_above_visible

Comment: Something important to note, unless html has css height: 100%, $('html').height will NOT work (Even though you might expect it should).  The method Allen gave always should.

Comment: Oops...ok - I subtracted the window height which should do it.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```